# How can I use a quote " or ' character within a string?

Tags: java, string, xpath, selenium-webdriver

am working on selenium webdriver using JAVA !

am trying to pass a string dynamically using the variable exp

```
String exp=",,,4'-TETRA; P-CHLORIDE";

d.findElement(By.xpath("a[contains(text(),\""+exp+"\")]//ancestor::table//parent::div")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

but its giving me an error :

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":

"a[contains(text(),\",,,4'-TETRA; P-CHLORIDE\")]//ancestor::table//parent::div"

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `'"+exp+"'` instead of `\""+exp+"\"` :

```
  d.findElement(By.xpath("a[contains(text(),'"+exp+"')]//ancestor::table//parent::div")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

**Update**

```
d.findElement(By.xpath('a[contains(text(),"'+exp+'")]//ancestor::table//parent::div')).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

Comment: the string exp contains single quote('), and hence the error occurs.

String exp=",,,4'-TETRA; P-CHLORIDE";

In this case there's a single quote(') after the number 4.

so it treats the exp variable as " ,,,4 " and not the complete exp string data.

Comment: @user3906784 Ok I've updated the answer, just reverse the quotes like I did in the update

Comment: @singe31--it worked....thanks a ton...

wuld definitely need help fr sum new  combinations....
but as for nw it worked...